# Do I have a MK5 or MK6 golf? How do I tell the difference?

Tags: golf

I have a 2008 1.9L VW Golf TDI Edition. Based on this car sale add I'm fairly sure it's an MK5, but it would be nice to have some kind of reliable resource as I'm going to start buying parts online and I don't want to stuff it up:

https://www.redbook.com.au/cars/details/2008-volkswagen-golf-edition-v-auto-my08/SPOT-ITM-286500/

I can't seem to find any information on how to tell them apart...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep, it's a Mk.V - it's a little excessive here to list all the myriad differences (the Mk. VI is essentially a re-engineered, facelifted Mk. V) but in this case there are some giveaways:

1. Engine - the Mk. VI didn't use the 1.9l TDI engine - they replaced it with the 2.0 TDI
2. Model Year - While *production* of the Mk. VI began in '08 the first model year it was used was 2009. Any 2008 car is going to be a Mk. V - and the only post-2008 Mk.V cars are 2.0 TFSI "GTI Edition 30" special edition cars (which ran until 2010)